# Create IMFByteStream from byte array

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to adapt a method that originally took a URL from Microsoft's MediaFoundation audio playback sample to instead take a source from a const char* array. Problem is, CreateObjectFromByteStream requires an IMFByteStream, not a const char*. How can I get what I need?

```
// Create a media source from a byte stream
HRESULT CreateMediaSource(const byte *data, IMFMediaSource **ppSource)
{
    MF_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;

    IMFSourceResolver* pSourceResolver = NULL;
    IUnknown* pSource = NULL;

    // Create the source resolver.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSourceResolver(&pSourceResolver);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Use the source resolver to create the media source.

    // Note: For simplicity this sample uses the synchronous method to create 
    // the media source. However, creating a media source can take a noticeable
    // amount of time, especially for a network source. For a more responsive 
    // UI, use the asynchronous BeginCreateObjectFromURL method.
    hr = pSourceResolver->CreateObjectFromByteStream(data,
        NULL,                       // URL of the source.
        MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE | MF_BYTESTREAM_CONTENT_TYPE,  // Create a source object.
        NULL,                       // Optional property store.
        &ObjectType,        // Receives the created object type. 
        &pSource            // Receives a pointer to the media source.
        );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the IMFMediaSource interface from the media source.
    hr = pSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(ppSource));

done:
    SafeRelease(&pSourceResolver);
    SafeRelease(&pSource);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: The stock implementations only work with a file.  You'll have to implement the interface yourself.  That surely has been done before, searching github.com would be wise.  I didn't see anything leap out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream()` to create an `IMFByteStream` from an `IStream` and you can create and `IStream` from a byte array using `SHCreateMemStream()`. The documentation at the time of writing is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatemfbytestreamonstream and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream

Here's a quick example:

```
// Generate a byte array
int sample_size = 0x100;
BYTE* sample_bytes = (BYTE*)malloc(sample_size)

// Create the IStream from the byte array
IStream* pstm = SHCreateMemStream(sample_bytes, sample_size);

// Create the IMFByteStream from the IStream
IMFByteStream* pibs = NULL;
MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream(pstm, &pibs);

// Clean up time
if (pibs)
    pibs->Close();
if (pstm)
    pstm->Release();
if (sample_bytes)
    free(sample_bytes)
```

Having an IStream interface but not a byte array interface seems to be a frequent occurrence in the Microsoft API. Thankfully creating an IStream is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I found easiest way to do this to just create tempfile and write *data there. Ugly hack, but worked good enough for me and if needed it can easily replaced by custom inmemory IMFByteStream implementation.

So code would be something like this:

```
Byte data[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};

HRESULT hr = S_OK;
hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

IMFByteStream *stream = NULL;
hr = MFCreateTempFile(
    MF_ACCESSMODE_READWRITE, 
    MF_OPENMODE_DELETE_IF_EXIST, 
    MF_FILEFLAGS_NONE, 
    &stream
);

ULONG wroteBytes = 0;
stream->Write(data, sizeof(data), &wroteBytes);
stream->SetCurrentPosition(0);

// make sure that wroteBytes is equal with data length
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. Using secondary store is slow and causes unnecessary write wear.