# Decoding an MP4 Stream From Network UWP

Tags: uwp, ms-media-foundation

In a standard Win32 C++ program, the approach seems to be to call `MFCreateTempFile` and use the `IMFByteStream` object from this to create a source reader with `MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream`: [Create IMFByteStream from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493191/create-imfbytestream-from-byte-array)

This method is unavailable in UWP and the second suggestion in the above link is also unavailable.

I want to decode my fragmented MP4 stream but I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this given the only solutions I've found are not possible.

Does anyone have a suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Can you check [`MediaSource.CreateFromStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.createfromstream?view=winrt-22621) method? you could use it to create media source from strem, and play it with mediaelementplayer.

Comment: Hello Nico, sorry that I didn't mention this, but I need to access the NV12 output afterwards for some post processing. We don't want to play the mp4 immediately afterwards. I think unfortunately I'm going to have to go lower and demux the MP4 and send the audio and video separately to the decoders myself. I also would like to have the solution that works on both Win32 and UWP, so I don't need to write the code twice for the same purpose.

Comment: Derive from official document MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream could support UWP apps.

Comment: It seems that I can't create the byte stream from a byte array however. There was a method that someone used to do this with SHCreateMemStream but these methods are also disabled in UWP. If there's a way to generate the byte stream then it should work but I struggled to find out how.

Comment: SHCreateMemStream is desktop only, it can't run in the UWP platform. What about FFmpeg?

Comment: I think it's the best option to just demux the bytes and then run it through the windows decoder. It's not too much trouble but I was just hoping there was a away to user the higher level source reader API. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity I'll summarise:

In order to use the `SourceReader` object with a raw byte stream, you need either `MFCreateTempFile` or `SHCreateMemStream`. Both methods are unavailable on UWP and are only available on desktop.

You will need to directly use the`CLSID_MSH264DecoderMFT` transform.